# insert element of 2 dimensional list to excel with openpyxl

Tags: python

I Have A List Like This ::

```
My_list = [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20], [5, 10, 15, 20, 25], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15] ]
```

I want To Insert Every List OF List Element In My_list In To One Column of Excel Spreadsheet With Openpyxl In Python ::

My Code Is This ::

```
for i in range(len(My_list)):
    for j in range(0, 5):
      text = sheet.cell(row= j, column= i)
      text.value = My_list[i]
```

But This Not Working. Anyone Can Help Me ???

Comment: Hi please consider reading: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @FChm what you mean????

Comment: Your question was originally poorly formatted, it helps if it is more readable (as it is now!)

Comment: Why exactly does this not work? Do you have an error code?

Comment: @FChm no i have not  error  i can write a list element to excel but  because  My_list is a 2 dimensional list i can not write this element to excel

Comment: @hosseinasghari: Show the **Full Traceback** you are geting. Try changing to `text.value = ', '.join('My_list[i])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because your are working with a 2D list...

When you reference the list:

```
print(My_list[0])
```

would return:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

But you want your assignment to the `text.value` attribute to be :

```
text.value = My_list[i][j]
```

which would assign the jth element of the ith list of `My_list` to `text.value`.

I'm not sure about your problem as a whole (as you have provided no context). However, in my opinion there are better ways of storing and writing such data. For example, you could use a pandas DataFrame and use it's [`.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method.

You could also look at taking advantage of the [`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) function. However, there is probably a valid reason for you using openpyxl which I understand!